# Sorting multiple fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, field

I have a table with 2 fields DATE and IMPORTANCE.  Now I want to sort both these fields in DESCENDING ORDER so that the rows are ordered by IMPORTANCE for EACH DATE.  For example, if sorted correct, rows should return like this:

```
Dec 3, 2010 - 10
Dec 3, 2010 - 10
Dec 3, 2010 - 8
Dec 3, 2010 - 7
Dec 3, 2010 - 3
Dec 3, 2010 - 1

Dec 2, 2010 - 10
Dec 2, 2010 - 9
Dec 2, 2010 - 3

Dec 1, 2010 - 8
Dec 1, 2010 - 5
Dec 1, 2010 - 5
Dec 1, 2010 - 4
```

Is there an **efficient** way of accomplishing this with only one query statement?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
ORDER BY `DATE` DESC, `IMPORTANCE` DESC
```

Comment: @Frank, DATE is a keyword, and in some cases, if you name a column with special words, your queries could have errors. `\`` escapes it.

Comment: No, DATE is not a keyword and ` isn't part of the ANSI SQL-standards. Use double quotes " to escape objectnames, MySQL also knows about double quotes, it's called ANSI_QUOTES. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Comment: ANSI_QUOTES is not the standard behaviour of Mysql and enabling it alters the syntax needed to delimit literal strings, thus very likely breaking much of the software developed for Mysql.

Comment: @Frank  in my own experience the backtick character does work as a quote marker for the field names in mysql  which is handy when you have a field name that has a space in it.   as:

`Select your name from yourtable `

doesn't work for me but 

`Select \`your name\` from yourtable`

does.

Answer (score 7):

You can add as many fields to **ORDER BY** as you want.

That'd be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `date` DESC, `importance` DESC
```