# Cannot sort by including the date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I enter the vehicleID and Date, the records must be sorted by using both vehicle ID and Date, however it doesn't get sorted from the Date but only with the vehicleID. How can I achieve this ?

```
if ($vid != null && $datepicker != null) {
    $conn = new Db();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM trip_details where vehicle_id = '".$vid."' AND date_t = '".$datepicker."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> ". $row["trip_id"]."</td>";
        echo "<td> ". $row["vehicle_id"]."</td>";
        echo "<td> ". $row["total_trip_km"]."</td>";
        echo "<td> ". $row["predict_fual"]."</td>";
        echo "<td> ". $row["date_t"]."</td>";
        // echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"view map\"></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Given you don't have any ORDER BY clause in your SQL query, you don't define any sort order at all, so there's no guarantee of records being returned in any particular order.... you need to specify an ORDER BY clause if you want a specific sort order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting multiple fields in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416880/sorting-multiple-fields-in-mysql)

Comment: The code you show us selects all rows with a particular vehicleID and Date, so it cannot be sorted on those two fields.

Comment: Well, you can also an array

Answer (score 1):

SQL makes no guarantee on the order results are returned from a `select` query unless you explicitly add an `order by` clause, so the fact that you observe the returned records sorted by the `vehicle_id` is coincidental. You need to add an `order by` clause to the query:

```
ORDER BY vehicle_id, date_t
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by needs to define to get the desired result.

try this

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM trip_details where
 vehicle_id='".$vid."' AND date_t='".$datepicker."' 
 ORDER BY vehicle_id DESC,date_t DESC";
```

Comment: In your answer date get sorted but vehicle id not sorted

Comment: @RoshanSenanayake now try. I have add sorting order on both columns.

Answer (score 0):

to sort you data by the columns you have define the name of columns in order by clause with order Acs(ascending) or Desc (descending)

e.g.

order by desc column1, asc column2